# I do mining on testnet, but cannot get ether

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, testnets

I'm doing mining on testnet as following, but I could not get any ether. Did I make any fault? Could you tell me how can I get ether on testnet?

```
$ build/bin/geth --testnet console
>miner.start()
>> I0305 05:12:06.326181    7460 backend.go:591] checking DAG (ethash dir: /home/vagrant/.ethash)
I0305 05:12:06.482523    7460 blockchain.go:1243] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 81 txs in 2.911192064s. #42701 [ac4ed672 / 19059a7c]
I0305 05:12:08.438405    7460 blockchain.go:1243] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 6 txs in 1.955358033s. #42957 [bf3c0c62 / eba3cbc2]
0.720423    7460 blockchain.go:1243] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) 
...

> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like your node is synced. You need to get up to the latest block before you can see any recent changed. Check a chain explorer like ether.camp to see the latest block and to get ether from the faucet.

Answer (score 2):

First of all wait until your node is fully synced with the blockchain. It will keep going downloading bunch of 256 blocks until it reaches the actual block and then it will keep downloading only 1 block at time, ever 10/20 seconds.

That will mean that you are synced with the network and you are downloading the last mined blocks in real time. After you are synced you can start mining, interacting, deploying contracts, send and receive ETH :)